# mapping to lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have this code:

```
l = [
    ("d", "d"),
    ("t", "-"),
    ("-", "t"),
    ("f", "d"),
    ("æ", ["ɑ", "ɪ"]),
    (["ɑ", "ɪ"], "æ"),
]
labels = [
    "perfect",
    "deletion",
    "insertion",
    "substitution",
    "one-to-many",
    "many-to-one",
]
dict = {}
for i in l:
    if i[0] == i[1]:
        dict[i] = labels[0]
    elif i[1] == "-":
        dict[i] = labels[1]
    elif i[0] == "-":
        dict[i] = labels[2]
    elif i[0] != i[1] and i[0] == "-" and i[1] == "-":
        dict[i] = labels[3]
    elif len(i[1]) >= 2:
        dict[i] = labels[4]
    elif len(i[0]) >= 2:
        dict[i] = labels[5]
```

when I print `dict`, it gives an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. This error is just for the last two `elif` statements. Any thoughts how to avoid this?

Comment: `dict` shouldn't be used for a variable name since it conflicts with the built-in function `dict` used to create dictionaries.  Especially bad (and confusing) in this case since you're creating dictionaries.

Comment: Isn't the last 3rd elif self contradictory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use lists (or tuples of lists) as dictionary keys, because lists are mutable.  But you can use tuples, so just change to this:

```
l = [('d', 'd'), ('t', '-'), ('-', 't'), ('f', 'd'), ('æ', ('ɑ', 'ɪ')), (('ɑ', 'ɪ'), 'æ')]
```